# How do I type-hint that a Python function returns instance of any class derived from a superclass?

Tags: python, django, type-hinting, typing

I've got a bunch of Django template inclusion tags, which take as an argument either a specific instance of a database object or a string/int, which is interpreted as the primary key of that database object. For example...

```
{% render_product product=obj %}
{% render_product product=42 %}
{% render_product product="42" %}
```

...all work fine and do the obvious: they render a template fragment with a particular Product instance, fetching it by primary key from the database, if needed. This is how Product and similar classes are defined:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # standard django model definition goes here
```

Here's what usually happens in such an inclusion tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("render_product.html")
def render_product(product: Union[Product, str, int] = None) -> dict:
    _product = None
    if isinstance(product, Product):
        _product = product
    elif isinstance(product, str) or isinstance(product, int):
        try:
            _product = Product.objects.get(pk=product)
        except (Product.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            pass
    return {"product": _product}
```

Since I've got the same pattern happening in dozens of inclusion tags, I'm trying to refactor it out, so that I've got something like:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("render_product.html")
def render_product(product: Union[Product, str, int] = None) -> dict:
    _product = fetch_object(Product, product)
    return {"product": _product}
```

Here's the fetch_object code:

```
def fetch_object(cls: Type[Model] = None, obj: Union[Model, str, int] = None):
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, str) or isinstance(obj, int):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get(pk=obj)
        except (cls.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            pass
    return None
```

My problem is: I have no idea how to specify the return type of that function. Basically it should be something like "instance of any class, which is derived from Model or None". But if I try something like...

```
def fetch_object(
    cls: Type[Model] = None, obj: Union[Model, str, int] = None
) -> Union[Model, None]:
```

...then PyCharm complains about "unresolved attribute reference" if I access a method on the fetched object, which is Product-specific, not Model-specific.

I'm trying to use more and more type-hinting in my Python code, because it has already saved my butt a few times, but this is one of those cases, where I have no idea what the correct way of doing it would be and my google-fu is failing me.

What is the correct type-hinting for fetch_object?

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer right now, but you want to use a a TypeVar.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar

Use the same TypeVar for your parameters and return type, that way PyCharm knows if you ask for a Product you get a Product back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do here is make your `fetch_object` function a [generic function](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-functions).

That is, rather then just saying that your function accepts any `Type[Model]`, capture exactly which kind of model you accept using a type variable, and specify that exact kind is the output. For example:

```
from typing import TypeVar

# The bound states that T can be bound to Model or any subclass of Model.
# If the bound keyword argument is omitted, we assume the bound is 'object'.
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Model)

def fetch_object(cls: Type[T] = None, obj: Union[T, str, int] = None) -> Optional[T]:
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, str) or isinstance(obj, int):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get(pk=obj)
        except (cls.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            pass
    return None
```

One minor note on stylistic conventions: I chose to name the typevar `T` here for brevity. The other common convention is to name your typevar something like  `_TModel` or `_ModelT`. That is, the underscore to make the variable private, and a longer name for readability.