# Type hinting for Django Model subclass

Tags: python, django, pycharm, type-hinting

I have helper function for Django views that looks like this (code below). It returns None or single object that matches given query (e.g. `pk=1`).

```py
from typing import Type, Optional

from django.db.models import Model

def get_or_none(cls: Type[Model], **kwargs) -> Optinal[Model]:
    try:
        return cls.objects.get(**kwargs)
    except cls.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Supose I have created my own model (e.g. `Car`) with its own fields (e.g. `brand`, `model`). When I asign results of `get_or_none` function to a varibale, and then retriveing instance fields, I get annoying warning in PyCharm of unresolved reference.

```py
car1 = get_or_none(Car, pk=1)

if car1 is not None:
    print(car1.brand) # <- Unresolved attribute reference 'brand' for class 'Model'
```

What's the propper type hinting to get rid of this warning and **get code completion for variable**)?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54423713/8601641) helps for you or not.

Comment: yeah, that kinda works, but I forgot to mention in my quiestion, thst I want to get code completion (edited it), anyway thanks

Comment: Since python 3.9 you can use native (not from typing) type[Model] and mypy will be ok with that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050962/12613082) answer to almost simmilar question. The solution is to use [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) from typing

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Optional

from django.db.models import Model


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Model)

def get_or_none(cls: Type[T], **kwargs) -> Optional[T]:
    ... # same code
```

And everything works fine: **no warnings** and **code completion**